# Hide/show collapse/expand buttons

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

While trying to use a shortcut, I managed to press the wrong keys, which hid the collapse/expand buttons, i.e. the minus/plus buttons that can collapse or expand a class. How can I show them again?

Comment: Which shortcut to deactivate the buttons did you use unintentionally?

Comment: I don't know, really. If I knew that, I wouldn't have to ask ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Toggle Folding `Ctrl + /` (numpad divide). For the list of all shortcuts : `Ctrl + Shift + L`